# Why should we use Invoke in .Net?

Tags: .net

If Invoke in .Net works on the Same Thread ,and blocking the Calling thread,Why should we use invoke? Cant we call the Method Directly instead of Using Invoke?
Is there any specific scenario where invoke Should be used?

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke` is useful when you don't know which method is to be executed at compile time.

Comment: That is not the purpose of `Invoke`.

Comment: The question is vauge...Func<T> for example, exposes an Invoke method.    The questions specifically asks if there is a specific scenario where Invoke should be used.  In the case of Func<T>.Invoke() for example, my answer is correct.

Comment: I think it's clear from the verbiage in the OP's question, but fair point. Edited to allow downvote removal.

Comment: Removed `invoke` tag from the question - this tag is for `Control.Invoke`